# Is there any way to keep borders of the data cells from Pandas Style when saving dataframe to Excel?

Tags: python, pandas

With `.style.set_table_styles` I can add borders to my df but when I write the df to excel file I see that it only keeps borders for header and index part. Borders of the data cells are disappearing. Here is the example code;

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]})

df1.style.set_table_styles([
    {"selector": "", "props": [("border", "1px solid black")]},
    {'selector': 'tbody td','props': [('border', '1px solid black')]},
    {"selector": "th", "props": [("border", "1px solid black")]}
                           ]
                           , axis=1, overwrite=False)
df1.to_excel('df.xlsx')
```

Am I missing something or this is not manageable with `pandas.style`?

Comment: as discussed in docs, pandas styler does not export styles added via `set_table_styles`. You must apply styles directly to cells using the `Styler.applymap` or `Styler.applymap_index` methods.

Comment: @Attack68 How can I applymap borders elementwise?

Comment: `df1.style.applymap(lambda v: "border: 1px solid black;")` will put a border around every tbody td data cell.  `df1.style.applymap_index(lambda v: "border: 1px solid red;", axis=0)` will do the same but red for every index cell

Comment: @Attack68 `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]})

df1 = df1.style.applymap_index(lambda v: "border: 1px solid red;", axis=1)
df1.to_excel('df.xlsx')` It seems like pandas styler does not export styles added via `applymap` or `applymap_index` either.

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/45312 identifies and fixes this bug. v1.5.0 was only released 2 weeks ago so you probably do not have the bug fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found my answer with `Styler.set_properties`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]})

df1 = df1.style.set_properties(**{'border-color': 'black', 'border-width': '1px', 'border-style': 'solid'})
df1.to_excel('df.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, but it doesn't use style, do you absolutely want it ?  :

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('df.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

border_fmt = workbook.add_format({'bottom':5, 'top':5, 'left':5, 'right':5})
worksheet.conditional_format(xlsxwriter.utility.xl_range(0, 0, len(df1), len(df1.columns)), {'type': 'no_errors', 'format': border_fmt})
writer.save()
writer.close()
```